# Improve BeautifulSoup parsing speed

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I got a 15MB-ish htm file in which I want to get the names from a table of values. Due to my rather limited knowledge of python, this is the best solution I've found to my problem, but the problem is that it is rather slow. Any way to parse the data faster or make the code run faster overall
?

I've changed the parser to lxml but didn't notice much of an improvement.
What I wanted to implement would be that as entries were added, BeautifulSoup would only search from that point onward, but I got no clue how to do it

```py
def stew(fp):
    with open(fp, encoding="utf8") as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f, features="lxml")
    return soup


def name_crawler(soup):
    i = 2
    while i < 6853:
        tasty = soup.select("tr.cItem:nth-child(" + str(i) + ") > td:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)")
        tastier = search('target="_blank">(.*)</a>', str(tasty))
        with open("database.json", "a+") as f:
            f.write(tastier.group(1) + "\n")
        i = i + 1
        print(" [+] Entry added for " + tastier.group(1))
```

Comment: What you're probably wanting to do is read in your json file first and create some sort of list of values already present, then have your scraper only grab data that `is not in` that list. I don't know what your data looks like or the html, so I can;t say exactly how you'd want to implement that fully. Can you share the url or html? Honestly don't know if that'll speed it up. I blieve the bottle neck comes with reading in the soup object `soup = BeautifulSoup(f, features="lxml")`. If it's a big file, that's what will take the longest, not necessarily iterating through the elements/tags.

Comment: @chitown88 I think that the bottleneck is in the parsing through the elements because as the script runs for longer, the longer it takes to print the Entry added message.
 Here's the [link](https://csgo.exchange/prices/)
 Was also having trouble implementing the whole check if it is there part too, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improving the code a bit made it run a slight bit faster but after changing to PyPy the code runs 10x faster

```py
def stew(fp):
    with open(fp, encoding="utf8") as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f, features="lxml")
    return soup


def sauce(soup):
    i = 2
    tastiest = []
    while i < 6853:
        tasty = soup.select("tr.cItem:nth-child(" + str(i) + ") > td:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)")
        tastier = search('target="_blank">(.*)</a>', str(tasty))
        i = i + 1
        tastiest.append(tastier.group(1))
        print(" [+] Entry added for " + tastier.group(1))
    with open("database_weapons.obj", "ab+") as f:
        pickle.dump(tastiest, f)
```

Edit: After reading the BS documentation, I used `SoupSieve` in order to only look through the a tags and now it runs at a much much faster speed

```py
def stew(fp):
    tags = SoupStrainer("a")
    with open(fp, encoding="utf8") as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f, features="lxml", parse_only=tags).prettify()
    return soup


def sauce(soup):
    i = 1
    tastiest = []
    while True:
        tastier = findall('730/(.*)" target="_blank', str(soup))
        tastiest.append(tastier[i])
        print(" [+] Entry added for " + tastier[i])
        i = i + 1
    with open("database_weapons.obj", "ab+") as f:
        pickle.dump(tastiest, f)
```